# Unable to configure the chrome with webdriver with latest version

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The current version of Chrome cannot be detected by my code. I am attempting to use the latest driver version. Here is my code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.maximize_window()
url = 'https://247sports.com/college/football/recruiting/'
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Initializing *Chrome* with *ChromeDriver*

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v114.0*** and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ***v114.0*** you can use the minimum code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 11, 2023 3:58:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```